# Throw all buttons to div except two

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to use JQuery to move all buttons from my body to one div, except buttons in header.

Div for throw rest of the buttons: `<div class='divButt'></div>`

In my header got just simple div with class i_COMPANY with 2 buttons, which have to stay.

this is my JQuery code:

```
body.find('input[type=button]').not('.i_COMPANY input[type=button]').appendTo(".divButt")
```

Comment: Could you please add your HTML to the question. Its hard to write selectors for a structure you can't see.

Comment: Well, I really can't paste here whole HTML document :P but it's not really hard i think.. in header i've got <div class="i_COMPANY">BUTTONS</div>, and I want them to stay.

In the rest of document got few buttons (even in <td></td>), but is that really big problem? This code should check whole html i think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried like you mentioned. It works for me. let me know if you see any error. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  ($('input[type=button]').not('.i_COMPANY input[type=button]')).appendTo(".divButt")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="i_COMPANY">
  <input type="button" value="test" />
</div>
<br>
<input type="button" value="1" />
<input type="button" value="2" />
<div class='divButt' style='border:1px solid #333'></div>
```

Comment: Lol, thanks ;) 

I'm trying to code in coffee, that's my problem i think :P but if this formule is good i'll check this